# Ubuntu Install screen is pixellated and has strange aspect ratio

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox, virtualization, visual-artifacts

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox (Windows 7 host), but keep running into the same problem regardless of what I tweak in the vm's settings:

[image: Loading Screen Error]

This is the second time I've installed Ubuntu. The first, using the same .iso, ran into the same issue but eventually succeeded (wish I could remember what I did), but I deleted the first machine because I didn't know any better and wanted to have more memory for it.

What's even happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling VirtualBox as well as redownloading the .ISO file.

If the error is persistent through that than your system might not fully support that kind of virtualization.